# Problem in finding out the referencing style

Tags: citations

I want to send an article to the Springer journal "Cluster Computing", but I have problem in understanding the referencing style of the journal. Here is an example of a citation in previous articles of this journal:

> Li, Z., Huang, Y., Liu, G., et al.: Challenges, designs, and
> performances of large-scale open-P2SP content distribution. IEEE
> Trans. Parallel Distrib. Syst. 24(11), 2181–2191 (2013)

Which style is this? It is not similar to Harvard, Vancouver etc.

Comment: If you tell us the name of the journal this would probably be much easier.

Comment: @StrongBad Cluster computing

Answer (score 1):

The referencing style for the Springer publication [Cluster Computing: The Journal of Networks, Software Tools and Applications](https://link.springer.com/journal/10586) is briefly outlined on the page of [submission guidelines](https://link.springer.com/journal/10586/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_References) for authors. The guidelines are sufficiently brief that it is inevitable there will be instances of reference types that aren't particularly well described by the guidelines, in which case, one is left to guess how to amend one of the described styles.

That said, there is a rather better way to approach the problem. The [Citations Styles website](https://editor.citationstyles.org), [includes a page](https://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fcluster-computing) for Cluster Computing which includes links to appropriate templates. If you use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org), [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/), or any other citation software that uses CSL style templates rather than pay-for proprietary style sheets, then you will be able to install the correct style for Cluster Computing by clicking the `Install` button on the linked page.

As for the answer to "which style is it?", the closest answer is *Springer's mathematics and physics style with brackets* (see the description on the CSL page).